# How to create a downloadable public link for files on server

Tags: linux, http, ftp

I am afraid my question could be very stupid, and also be duplicate. But I didn't manage to find what I want after looking for some similar questions on this site.

My question is simple, I have a big file, i.e. 1GB on my Ubuntu server, and I want to share this file with other users. How can I create a URL address for public users, in other words, when one user click this URL, the download will automatically start without demanding a username and password, just like we download many stuff (pdf, music) when we find an usable url with google.

Someone suggests me to setup an anonymous ftp. I think it's a possible solution, but I didn't succeed to accomplish it. Can some one give me more details how I achieve my goal, (with or without ftp will both ok).

Thanks for any help, and I am very grateful for some examples, or some tutorials !

Comment: When someone vote down my question, could you please give me a reason for your action ?! That will help me to pose more "intelligent" questions!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Install Apache2

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Place your into file the /var/www/ directory (might need root privileges for this)

```
sudo cp yourfile /var/www/yourfile
```

Access the file with the following link:

```
http://your-ip-address/yourfile
```

If your running under a router or firewall, you might have to open port 80 and forward it to your pc.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer, that's exactly what I want, and the whole process is really much simpler than I expected. :-)

Comment: showing `The requested URL /yourfile was not found on this server`

Comment: Did look link [Open TCP Port 80 in Windows Firewall](https://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall) but still same error

Comment: save file here : /var/www/html to make it downloadable

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume your filename is `foobar.iso`.

You could just place it in your web root, and give the link `example.com/foobar.iso` to people. This will download the file.

Optionally, place it in a directory `downloads`. The download link will then be `example.com/downloads/foobar.iso`.